# Generation of Links using GSON instead of serialization of whole object tree

Tags: java, json, hyperlink, gson

i want to serialize a object tree with gson. It works fine, but i don't want to transfer the whole Tree. Especially i want to generate links to child objects.

For Example:

```
class BookStrore {
  public String name;
  public List<Book> books;
}

class Book {
  public int id;
  public String name;
}
```

Serializing an instance of BookStore would lead to something like:

```
{ name : 'bookStoreName', 'books' : [ { id: '3', name: 'blubb' }, ... ] }
```

but want to have links like:

```
{ name: 'bookStoreName', 'books': [ book: 'http://example.com/book/3', ... ] }
```

Does anyone know how to achieve this with GSON?
I'm not sticked to GSON. If anyone have another solution, it's welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can find a piece of the answer with anotation

> http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-json-parsing-gson-tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the link. It made me think again on the problem from another point of view. I finally recognised that the problem is within my approach, because if claim that a "BookStore" has a list of books, there has to be a list of Books and not a list of references. Sure, in Java, a list of books is also a list of references. So i could start generating proxies. For this, i have to modify the serializer/ deserializer. But this would violate the default, in my case java, programming model. Another approach is, which i prefer because its more clear an system independent, to create special data transfer objects. In this case BookLinks and let the BookStore class contain a list of BookLinks. I think thats the right way because it reveals what it is, a link and not an object.